# Symbol Constructor error in Typescript: [ts] Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, types, symbols, new-operator

I'm new to typescript and am trying to use ES6 Symbol constructor. How do I properly resolve this ts lint issue without using `any`?

```
        const symbol = new Symbol(path);
```

What I don't want to do:

```
        const symbol = new (Symbol as any)(path);
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `new` with symbols, and typescript is alerting you to that fact. Your code (with or without the `as any`) throws an exception when run:

```js
const path = 'something';
const symbol = new Symbol(path);
```

Instead, just drop the new. This will make the code no longer throw exceptions, and will make typescript no longer tell you there's a problem.

```
const symbol = Symbol(path);
```